# Python: Randomly mix two lists

Tags: python, list, random, mutation

I'm having some trouble mixing two lists together to make a new list of the same length.

So far I have randomly selected two lists from a bunch of lists called parent 1 and parent 2. This is what I have so far but the `output_list` line doesn't work.

```
parent1 = listname[random.randint(1,popsize)]
parent2 = listname[random.randint(1,popsize)]
output_list = random.choice(concatenate([parent1,parent2]), length, replace=False)
print(output_list)
```

The outcome I want is:
if `parent1 = [1,2,3,4,5]` and `parent2 = [6,7,8,9,10]`
then a possible outcome could be `[1,2,3,9,10]` or `[1,7,2,5,6]` or `[1,2,7,4,5]`.

Anybody have any ideas?

(the context is two sets of genes which breed to form a child with a mix of the parents genes)

Comment: Sound like genetic algorithm :D

Comment: Is performance important to you?

Comment: @enamoria you know it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.shuffle) after concatenating `parent_1` and `parent_2` and pick a slice of the same length as `parent_1`:

```
import random

parent_1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
parent_2 = [6,7,8,9,10]

c = parent_1 + parent_2
random.shuffle(c)

result = c[:len(parent_1)]
print(result) # [4, 5, 10, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you construct genetic algorithms, it is preferable a value from a parent keeps the same index in child array, like genes in chromosomes.

You can performs that with numpy :

```py
import numpy as np
male = np.random.choice(100, 5)   # array([25, 90, 25, 96, 91])
female = np.random.choice(100, 5) # array([98, 19, 17, 78, 29])
np.choose(np.random.choice(2, 5), [male, female])
# array([98, 19, 25, 96, 29])
np.choose(np.random.choice(2, 5), [male, female])
# array([25, 90, 25, 78, 29])
```